# Is there a way to modify environment variable in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I have written a lambda function which does some processing.

There is 1 environment variable which is set by default.

Is there a way I can change it after every run ?

Comment: You can change your environment variable by hand or programmatically with a script, but storing dynamic data is not what environment variables are for, you usually use some sort of database for that. What is your exact use case for wanting to change it at every run ?

Comment: Why you use environment variable for this case? why not get this value from database or something...

Comment: @giuseppedeponte But is it a good idea to use database for single variable ? Eg. Let's say i am maintaining a counter (i =0 ) how many times my lambda function run.  In my nodejs lambda script i want to do i++ so that my Env variable increment by 1. Any link to how i can change AWS lambda environment variable ?

Comment: Some sort of database... Could be just a file, like a JSON or CSV or just text file.

Comment: In your example ‘using a counter to check how mamy times a lamda is run’, you can just have a normal counter in your code but *outside* of the lambda handler. That allows you to keep all sorts of state (eg: in-process cache, etc) between lambda invocations on the *same* lambda instance. If you need to preserve state over different lambda instances, use a DB.

Comment: @Geert-Jan  That's the perfect answer what I need. I wonder why noone else knows this. If you could mention this as an answer , I can mark that as accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: you can store parameter, it will accessible over different lamda function and you can also deal with store parameter as an ENV and it will also work accrod different lamda.  storing outside in the event hanlder may work but it will lost once you update the lamda function. also you will not bother with DB

Comment: ohh..i never thought that!! :)

Comment: @Adiii Sure you should!!  Please let me know how can i store parameter? If you could, how can i access.

Comment: @Thinker you can check the answer. just go to aws console create secret and you will get complete code.

Comment: @Geert-Jan Can you please elaborate more on how to store normal counter in code outside of lambda handler?

Comment: @mohitsahu: Something like: 

`````
let counter = 0;

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    counter++;
    console.log(`This instance of the function has been called ${counter} times.`);
};
`````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not happy with DB, as suggested in comment then you can use [AWS store parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) which will answer your this query.

> way to modify environment variable in AWS Lambda?

You can consume Your environment variable from the [store parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html), also it will keep the state across different lambda function, Variable outside handle may work as suggested @Jan, but what if you update the lambda function?

So, for example, the flow will be

```
If store-paramter == true;
 #do the job,after job done
 #update store-paramter value
 store-paramter=false
else
 #play with with value
```

once you generate [secret in secretsmanager](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/home?region=us-west-2#/home) , AWS will popup with complete code in a different language just copy the code and paste it in lambda that sample but you should assign permission to lambda.

Also, you explore a handy npm package [aws-param-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-param-store).

BTW application should not update ENV, but to deal with your use case you can follow.

You can check this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sharing-secrets-with-aws-lambda-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) too from scratch how to set and consume secret in lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are made to pass settings to your Lambda. They aren't the right tool for keeping your state.

[DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) is a serverless database made exactly for that purpose. It is easy to create a table that will store just one value.

Within [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%23always-free) you can get 25GBs and opportunity to make up to 25 write/read requests a second.